# PyQGIS QgsTask AssertionError

Tags: pyqgis, assertionerror

I am trying the [`QgsTask`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsTask.html) feature from PyQGIS.

There is a large function which needs to be run in a task.

```py
def starttask(self):
    task = QgsTask.fromFunction("Perform Task", self.chartload)

    QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task)

def chartload(self, task):
    self.chartreader("CHART.000") #this is a heavy function

    self.splitdep()
    self.project.addMapLayers(self.layer_list2)
    self.canvas.setLayers(self.layer_list2) 
    self.canvas.setExtent(self.BUISGL.extent())    

    self.project.removeMapLayer(self.DEPARE.id())
```

The function `starttask` is assigned to a pushbutton.

EDIT: As @bugmenot123 suggested, I adjusted the code, but the task won't run at all at the moment.

*The problem is that an exception is thrown when the large function is finished*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 1444, in starttask
     task = QgsTask.fromFunction("Reading Chart", self.chartload(self.layer_list2), on_finished=self.completed)
   File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr\python\qgis\core\additions\fromfunction.py", line 50, in fromFunction
     assert function
AssertionError
```

I can't seem to find a clear explanation for this exception.

Does somebody know when or what throws this exception?

QGIS 3.22 LTR

---

As @bugmenot123 said i had to run `QgsTask.fromFunction` different.
But i couldn't get it to work.
So in order to make my own situation work i made the following code

```py
class TaskClass(QgsTask): #task Class
    def __init__(self, mywnd_instance):
        QgsTask.__init__(self)
        self.mywnd_instance = mywnd_instance 
        self.mywnd_instance.chartload() # the heavy function inside the main class

class MyWnd(QMainWindow): #main class
    def __init__(self):
        self.starttask() # you can start/connect the task where you like ofcourse

    def starttask(self):
        task = TaskClass(self) # i pass self because the heavy function is in the main class
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task)

    def chartload(self):
        self.chartreader("CHART.000") # This is heavy
        #self.fromDB() # This is not, but nice it's separated from the gui
```

why `QgsTask.fromFunction` won't work, is still a mystery

Comment: Does `self.chartload(self.layer_list2)` return a function object or is that the function *call* you would like to make?

Comment: it does not return any items, however i pass that list to eventually add those layers to the canvas and project, i'll try without at the moment EDIT: it still throws the same error

Comment: You are supposed to pass just a function object, e.g. `self.chartload` (note the missing `()`!). If you need to pass parameters, check out `functools.partial`. Careful with GUI things, you might run into crashes if you know know about threading.